# OSM roadways shapefile - Completing missing road names

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, road

I have a shapefile for the road network in Portugal that I downloaded from a OpenStreetMap mirror site (geofabrik), dated about a month ago.

A little context beforehand for those not familiar with the road naming system in Portugal -- since it may not be the same for your country--: We have municipal roads, which usually belong within city limits; national roads, that serve a purpose of connecting the different cities, without using highways; primary and complementary itineraries, which act as fast roads --like highways, but with a few differences--; and highways. There are others, but these are the main ones.

Currently I'm using the "type" field (motorway, primary, secondary,...), to establish some sort of hierarchy, but this doesn't work for me because I need to separate itineraries from highways, and national from municipal.
What I would like to know is if there is any way for me to complete the "name" (XX Street, Y Avenue,...) or the "ref" (Highway 1, Municipal Street 273,...) fields, since they are lacking a lot of values, and thus being able to use the Query Builder to sort them all out.

I searched a lot before writing this question and most of the posts I see are about missing roads, and this is not the case: as far as I know, my road network is complete.

I am also aware that there is a new shapefile available to download on the geofabrik, dated yesterday, but unless they had a huge overhaul, the road names will still be missing.

Comment: Have you looked for official data sources? Especially the primary roads should be available under INSPIRE. Also, currently it is unclear, what your question is? Are you really asking how to fill in attributes?

Comment: INSPIRE only has information on highways, or the roads in Azores, so that won't help me. My question is: Is there a way for me to get an outside source to fill in the blanks? For example, is there a way for me to use the basemap information (also OpenStreetMap) to gather all the street names?

Comment: Yes, there is a way: Edit everything manually.

Comment: Well... obviously that is a way.... But I am dealing with 58k+ entries, in which less than 4k are complete. Manual entry is not a feasible way to do this.

Comment: You'd first need a dataset which contains all the road names, and has any common ID with your current data. Then it would be possible.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, and I know how to join datasets. I was hoping that someone could point to a more complete dataset, preferably with a common ID. I haven't been able to find a complete list of roads in Portugal, either. Maybe it doesn't exist, since most of our state companies rely on OpenStreetMap.

Comment: Since you're looking for data, I suggest you ask this question (way more precise) on OpenData.SE.

Comment: Note: Geofabrik is not a mirror site for Shapefiles. They have been specifically created by Geofabrik and are not available from openstreetmap.org. If some of the data is unavailable, be sure to check osm.org first.